# How to merge multiple column into one column with same table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to merge some column value into one column with varchar/nvarchar data type.

I tried to use Computed Column Specification in Table Designer, but I only know how to compute int data type.

```
| Column1 |  | Column2 |  | Column3 |  |MergedColumn|
|    A    |  |    B    |  |    C    |  |    AB-C    |
|    A1   |  |    B1   |  |    C1   |  |  A1B1-C1   |
```

I need that result in MergedColumn.

Comment: You can try using `concat` the columns you want and update the last column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I use `concat` as `select`, but I need the result like a normal column.

Comment: I think you want to look up views and computed columns.

Comment: So @shawnt00 you mean that is possible only in views?

Comment: No, I think you could probably choose one or the other to do what you need. It sounds like you might have tried a computed column though it's unclear what you meant by the "int" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function should work here:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    CONCAT(Column1, Column2, '-', Column3) AS MergedColumn
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: How to place this syntax as column?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD MergedColumn AS CONCAT(Column1, Column2, '-', Column3) PERSISTED` that should do it.